# Exporting SVG into the local Resource directory

Tags: c++, qt, svg

I am trying to reach the qt resource folder without success. It works if I export into an other folder like `C:\\Temp\\18_25_21_18_09_2014.svg`, but it doesn't work if I use an URL like `:/Temp/18_25_21_18_09_2014.svg`.

Here is the code:

```
QString fileName(":/Temp/Temp" + QDateTime(QDateTime::currentDateTime()).toString("hh_mm_ss_dd_MM_yyyy") + ".svg");
QSvgGenerator generator;
generator.setFileName(fileName);
generator.setSize(this->size());
generator.setViewBox(QRect(QPoint(0,0), this->size()));
generator.setTitle(tr("bubble_svg"));
generator.setDescription(tr("bubble_svg"));
_painter.begin(&generator);
_painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
_painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
this->render(&_painter);
_painter.end();
```

Also I created a prefix called `Temp` and a folder called `Temp`.

It looks like that also QDirIterator can reach the folder, only the QSvgGenerator couldn't.

```
  QDirIterator it(":/Temp/Temp", QDir::Files, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
     while (it.hasNext()) {
          qDebug() << "FILE FOUND " << it.next();
     }
```

The result of this part of code:

```
FILE FOUND ":/Temp/Temp/18_35_19_18_09_2014.svg"
```

I appreciate every idea. Thanks for dropping by and taking time with the questions!

Comment: If you set prefix Temp then maybe you need `://Temp/Temp`? Anyways try to go to the Resources in Qt creator, choose your file, right click , copy res path to clipboard and paste this path

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried every permutation of the URL. I would like to create a file using QSvgGenerator not to load one. However I did a test, and the folder is reachable, check the updated question.

Comment: I run your code on my computer but with simple path like `gen.svg`, it works perfectly, but I can't understand,do you want save this file on your filesystem or in Qt resource system?

Comment: Thanks for your time @Chernobyl. Maybe it isn't possible at all, the truth is that I don't know, but I would like to save the file into he Qt resource system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understood and post it as answer.

Unfortunately it is impossible. `Qt Resource System` forbid this. As documentation said:

The `Qt resource system` is a platform-independent mechanism for storing binary files in the application's executable. It means that resources are read only, thuis files compiled into the executable, you can't write it because this files storing in your exe file. Especially an executable can’t modify itself while it is running. You’ll have to re-compile the `QRC` file (using `RCC`) and then re-build the `EXE` file, if one of the resources has changed.

As you can see, you should provide another way to storing and using your files.

I hope it was useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I accept it. Do you know what is the best way for storing files platform independently near the executable?

Comment: @flatronka near the executable :) `generator.setFileName(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("hh_mm_ss_dd_MM_yyyy"));`

Comment: thanks and I suppose I can create a folder with this call: 'QDir().mkdir("MyFolder");' ?

Comment: @flatronka it is normal practise too, in this case files will be placed in one directory and there will be no rubbish near exe file.